# Euler path in cube

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose we have the cube $3\times3\times3$ divided by $1\times1\times1$ cubes.

We want to prove that there isn't path from an edge cube to the cube in the center which passes through every cube and doesn't pass through an already passed cube.

We can only go to adjacent cube if the two cubes have common side.I know the fact that we have Euler path if and only we have $2$ edges with odd degree but clearly in the $3\times3\times3$  cube if each cube is edge and each has vertices it is easy to see that there are more than $2$ cubes with odd vertices.Does this mean that there is no Euler path and we can't reach the middle cube?

Comment: The Euler path goes along every edge in a diagram.  The Hamiltonian path goes through every vertex in a graph.  I think your problem is a Hamiltonian path, through the 27 cubes.

Comment: When you say an *edge* cube, do you mean one of the eight corner cubes?

Comment: yes brian scott

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Eight corner cubes? I thought he is talking about the twelve edge cubes.

Comment: @Roy: The earlier version multiplies the sides of the cube by $10$, but it’s the same problem, and the hint that I gave there applies just as well to your question. Feel free to leave a comment for me under my answer there if you have questions.

Comment: @peterwhy: I had the advantage of having seen the question before, both here and elsewhere, and suspecting that it might be a language problem.

Answer (score 0):

The precise statement is that you have an Euler path from vertex $a$ to vertex $b$ if and only if the only vertices with odd degree are $a$ and $b$. So yes, that is what it means.

Comment: so my solution is correct?